# Continue foreach loop even after an exception is encounterd in asp.net core razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, exception, foreach, razor-pages

I have to log the exception into a database table and continue the foreach loop without any interruptions .
When i am trying to insert the exception into database table in catch block,its throwing null referenece exception. Here is my code.

```
        foreach (var row in toEmailList)
        {
            foreach (var matrix in emailMatrixList.Where(u => names.Contains(u.BusinessUnit)))
            {
                // Send to Staff + Supervisor/Manager
                if (row.DaysDueDate <= 42 && row.DaysDueDate >= 28)
                {
                    if (matrix.StaffID.Equals(row.StaffID))
                    {
                        if (!row.EmailLevelSent.Equals("First Level"))
                        {
                            try { 
                                var message = new MailMessage();
                                var bodyText = "<div style='font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>" +
                                "<p>Dear @FirstName @LastName,</p>" +
                                "<p>This is a notification to remind you that you have <b>@DaysDueDate</b> days to complete the following online <b>@TrainingTitle</b> training.</p>" +
                                "<p>Please remember to complete the training course within the next few days.</p>" +
                                "<p>If you do not complete this training within the required time frame, this information will be forwarded to your next level manager.</p>" +
                                "<p>Thank you very much,<br/>Kind regards,</p>" +
                                "<p>Manager</p>" +
                                "</div>";
                                var body = bodyText.Replace("@FirstName", row.FirstName).Replace("@LastName", row.LastName).Replace("@DaysDueDate", row.DaysDueDate.ToString()).Replace("@TrainingTitle", row.TrainingTitle.ToString());
                                if (matrix.StaffEmail.Contains("@domain.com"))
                                {
                                    message.To.Add(new MailAddress(row.StaffEmail));
                                }
                                else if (matrix.ManagerEmail.Contains("@domain.com"))
                                {
                                    message.To.Add(new MailAddress(matrix.ManagerEmail));
                                }
                                message.From = new MailAddress(_from);
                                message.Subject = "Training Notification for " + row.TrainingTitle;
                                if (matrix.ManagerEmail.Contains("@domain.com"))
                                {
                                    message.CC.Add(new MailAddress(matrix.ManagerEmail));
                                }
                                else if ((matrix.ManagerEmail.Contains("N/A")) || (matrix.ManagerEmail.Contains("NA")) || (matrix.ManagerEmail.Contains("#N/A")) || (matrix.ManagerEmail.Contains("na")))
                                {
                                    message.To.Add(new MailAddress(row.StaffEmail));
                                }
                                
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(matrix.InTheLoop))
                                {
                                    message.CC.Add(new MailAddress(matrix.InTheLoop));
                                }
                                message.Body = string.Format(body);
                                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                             
                                await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
                                TempData["MailSent"] = "MailSent";

                                Debug.WriteLine("Sending first level email to " + row.FirstName + " " + row.LastName);
                                Debug.WriteLine("CC: " + message.CC.ToString());
                                row.EmailLevelSent = "First Level";
                                Debug.WriteLine("First Level email sent to " + row.FirstName);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                FailedEmails.StaffID = row.StaffID;
                                FailedEmails.FirstName = row.FirstName;
                                FailedEmails.LastName = row.LastName;
                                FailedEmails.StaffEmail = row.StaffEmail;
                                FailedEmails.ExceptionLog = e.Message;
                                FailedEmails.SentDate = DateTime.Now;
                                _context.Entry(FailedEmails).State = EntityState.Added;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated, is there anything i am missing. Thanks!

Comment: When debugging,which row you will get `null referenece exception`?

Comment: @YiyiYou, i am getting all the row values, the issue is with FailedEmails.StaffID this part. when i tried to insert it using raw sql query,there was no exception at all.Its inserting data.